# Erro no código que não encontro - Criar CNPJ (Java)

Tags: java

Bom dia pessoal, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Possuo esse código Java que deve criar número de CNPJ válido. No entanto, a resposta é `Class GeradorCnpj` quando deveria vir o número.

Segue o código:

```
public class GeradorCnpj {
    public String geraCNPJ() throws Exception {
     int digito1 = 0, digito2 = 0, resto = 0;
     String  nDigResult;
     String numerosContatenados;
     String numeroGerado;
     Random numeroAleatorio = new Random();
      //numeros gerados
     int n1 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n2 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n3 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n4 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n5 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n6 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n7 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n8 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n9 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10);
     int n10 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10); 
     int n11 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10); 
     int n12 = numeroAleatorio.nextInt(10); 
     int soma = n12*2 + n11*3 + n10*4 + n9*5 + n8*6 + n7*7 + n6*8 + n5*9 + n4*2 + n3*3 + n2*4 + n1*5;
     int valor = (soma / 11)*11;
     digito1 = soma-valor;
      //Primeiro resto da divisão por 11.
     resto = (digito1 % 11);
     if(digito1 < 2){
      digito1 = 0;
     }
     else {
       digito1 = 11-resto;
     }
     int soma2 =  digito1*2 + n12*3 + n11*4 + n10*5 + n9*6 + n8*7 + n7*8 + n6*9 + n5*2 + n4*3 + n3*4 + n2*5 + n1*6 ;
     int valor2 = (soma2 / 11)*11;
     digito2 = soma2-valor2;
      //Primeiro resto da divisão por 11.
     resto = (digito2 % 11);
     if(digito2 < 2){
      digito2 = 0;
     }
     else {
       digito2 = 11-resto;
     }
     //Conctenando os numeros
     numerosContatenados = String.valueOf(n1) + String.valueOf(n2) +"."+ String.valueOf(n3) + String.valueOf(n4) +
                           String.valueOf(n5) +"."+ String.valueOf(n6) + String.valueOf(n7) +String.valueOf(n8)+"/"+
                           String.valueOf(n9) + String.valueOf(n10) + String.valueOf(n11) +
                           String.valueOf(n12)+"-";
     //Concatenando o primeiro resto com o segundo.
      nDigResult = String.valueOf(digito1) + String.valueOf(digito2);
      numeroGerado = numerosContatenados+nDigResult;
      System.out.println("Digito 2 ->"+digito2);
      System.out.println("CNPJ Gerado " + numeroGerado);
      return numeroGerado;
    }
    public String mostraResultado() throws Exception{
     String resultadoCNPJ = geraCNPJ();
     return resultadoCNPJ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você instanciou um objeto a partir desta classe pra utilizar os métodos da mesma?

Comment: Não vejo erro algum no código, você pode ver o resultado que obtive com o uso do mesmo aqui: https://ideone.com/gwfdIQ

Comment: Rômulo, utilizei seu exemplo e continua retornando "Class GeradorCNPJ".
Estranho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei o código e invoquei no seguinte método main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GeradorCnpj gerador = new GeradorCnpj();
    System.out.println(gerador.mostraResultado());
}
```

O output foi o seguinte:

> Digito 2 ->0
>   CNPJ Gerado 09.231.247/0962-80
>   09.231.247/0962-80

Comment: Patrícia, utilizei o seu exemplo.. Continua retornando "Class Gerador CNPJ"...
O que será que pode ser?

Comment: Com está a compilar o código e a executá-lo?

Comment: Patrícia, utilizei o seguinte código:

Comment: O limite de caracteres excede. Não consigo incluir o código. Mas o código é o mesmo do meu post.
Poderia verificar?

Comment: Está a utilizar algum IDE para compilar e executar a aplicação?

Comment: Patrícia, estou utilizando a ferramenta Jmeter (automação).

Comment: Então acredito que isso já tenha a ver com configuração do teste no Jmeter. Consegui replicar sem problemas. Pode seguir o seguinte exemplo, talvez ajude: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-custom-jar-beanshell-sampler-jmeter-lakshmi-narayan/